# Image size for custom Interstitial ads in admob

Tags: android, image, admob, ads, interstitial

I want to use my own image for interstitial ads in admob, what is the best size for the image (width x height) so it looks good across device?

I know interstitial ads is full screen, but I worry if it will looks bad if loaded in bigger screen device.

Also what is the appropriate image format for the ads? Is PNG enough?

Comment: if you want interstitial ads in admob then you have to give image on admob console.

Comment: @Harshid: yes, that means I can upload my own image, right? The question is about the size of image (wxh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this [Link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/interstitial).

There is no need to define a separate ad unit for landscape mode. You can simply add the landscape size (e.g. 480x320 for smartphones) to line items targeting the interstitial ad unit and include a creative with the landscape size in addition to the regular portrait size.

```
  Phones: 320x480 (portrait), 480x320 (landscape)
  Tablets: 768x1024 (portrait), 1024x768 (landscape)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. So if I want to target phone and tablet, do I need to upload two images for each phone and tablet? And then in source code, what is the best way to determine if device is phone or tablet and then conditionally use the correct ads id?